# What is a modem "voice view mode"?

Tags: modem

I'm trying to use a 56K modem to make a phone call, so I need to know if it's a "voice" modem.. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set#Detecting_voice_mode), if a modem answers the `AT+FCLASS=?` command listing an `8`, it means that the modem **is** a voice modem. In my case though, I get the following:

```
AT+FCLASS=?                             
0,1,1.0,80
```

[Here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3944) it says that "8.0" is "voice view", but what does it mean? Is this something *more* that a voice modem, or something less?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set gives you some useful commands you could try out. AT+VSM=? should list all the voice codecs the modem supports.  If it returns a list of codecs then this modem will handle voice.

Comment: That command returns `ERROR`, so I think this solves my problem, thanks :) But still I'm wondering, what is this "voice view"?